# CSS gradients and opacity

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, css-gradients

Below is some css that is used to create a radial gradient pattern.
My question: Is it possible to add opacity to the colors giving them a ghost like effect? Can one use RGBa instead of Purple??

I tried the above but couldn't get it to work as expected

```
/* Note the RADIAL */
background: repeating-radial-gradient(
  circle,
  purple,
  purple 10px,
  #4b026f 10px, 
  #4b026f 20px
);
```

Many thanks, 
P

Comment: Yes. Didn't you give it a try?

Comment: What didn't work as expected? Can you show an image of what you expected and what the output was?

Comment: You can always use RGBa(127,13,126,1) to replace the default html purple color

Answer (score 3):

You can use RGBa values within repeating radial gradients but you need to make sure that both the start point and end point are set.

Try changing the background colour in `.bg` and see the gradient colours change.

```css
.bg {
  background: red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
}
.gradient {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  background: repeating-radial-gradient(circle, rgba(128,0,128, 0.5), rgba(128,0,128, 0.5) 10px, rgba(75, 2, 111, 0.5) 10px, rgba(75, 2, 111, 0.5) 20px);
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="gradient"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following lines can also be used to enable opacity for a div. You can use it in most cases.

```
.div_element{
 opacity : 0.9; /*Value can be changed to increase or decrease opacity level*/
 filter : alpha(opacity=90);
}
```

Comment: in this case, i would argue that rgba is a better option. it allows you to have different opacities at different parts of the gradient.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. I was just demonstrating an other method which may help him in other situation to apply opacity.